# LoadLibrary failing on Win7 32 bit, succeeding on Win XP 32 bit

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a 3rd party dll (i.e. I have no source code) into my application. On a windows xp 32 bit system, it loads fine, but on a windows 7 system it fails to load, citing error #998 from GetLastError()

I used a dll export viewer to view the imported and exported symbols of the dll, and observed that all but 3 dlls listed in the import table came from this 3rd party vendor. The ones that didn't are:
    kernel32.dll
    mingwm10.dll
    msvcrt.dll

Here is the code I am using to do the import:

```
SetDllDirectory(L"c:\\dlls");
HMODULE tempDLL = LoadLibrary(L"mydll.dll");
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

Any tips on how to go about debugging this, please?

Edit: My thanks to everyone for the answers, and this is what I have discovered so far:
a) The application toolkit package did not prove to be that useful (see below)
b) Colleague A can get the dll to load on his win 7 machine and colleague B cannot, so it something sporadic
c) Running as admin did not change anything

Comment: Strange thing, I can load kernel32.dll & msvcrt.dll without any issues on Win7. Are you sure that LoadLibrary returning NULL in you case?

Comment: You have mingwm10.dll in your dll load path somewhere?

Comment: Just a guess from the top of my head.
Are you trying to run you application "As Administrator" ? If not, please try and tell us the result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reponse. In answer:

Comment: Thank you for the quick reponse. In answer:  
a) All the dlls (including mingw10.dll) are in the same directory as passed to SetDllDirectory
b) It is indeeed returning NULL, confirmed in the debugger
c) Running as admin in windows 7 works! What does that mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: @Andrew Now question will be: what directory you actually use in function `SetDllDirectory(L"c:\\dlls");`. This issue can occur if you use directories in which you do not have access without Admin rights or if they are restricted by UAC.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=24da89e9-b581-47b0-b45e-492dd6da2971&displaylang=en) (it is a free toolset) to find out why it fails on Windows 7. Hope this will help, it looks like a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [Data Execution Prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) (DEP) disabled?

This is normally enabled by default on Vista and above, but disabled on XP. If your DLL has a bug causing it to execute data, this could show up during the LoadLibrary call.